# Pause game shell window on tkinter and open a new shell window

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, tkinter-canvas

Using Tkinter python.

I am creating a game and in which I have a **quit** button. I want when I click on quit button my game pause and open a new shell. If I click on **NO** button then game shell resume working. If I click on **Yes** button then quit the game. **Yes** button is working fine. I have problem on when I click on quit button game should be paused and resume when clicking on the no button

```
def quit_function():
    YES = Button(tk9,text="YES",font=("Showcard Gothic",10), command= os._exit(0), fg='white', bg='red', width=10)
    NO = Button(tk9,text="NO",font=("Showcard Gothic",10), command= tk9.destroy, fg='white', bg='red', width=10)

    #**Quit Button**
    QUIT  = Button(tk3,text="QUIT",font=("Showcard Gothic",10), command= quit_function, fg='white', bg='red', width=10)
```

This is working fine but not major and the main problem is I am not able to pause and resume the game

Comment: I would advise looking into the tkMessageBox package which gives you dialog windows to use. You can attach an event to the window being closed/a button which will then show a dialog window.

Comment: I want two options when I click on Quit button and my game should be pause when click on Quit button

Answer (score 0):

you can use a game loop to update your game and test if it's paused or not, and the yes or no can be done by a messagebox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def quit_callback():
    global pause
    pause = True
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "Wanna leave?"):
        root.destroy()
    pause = False

def game_loop():
    while True:
        if not pause:
            print("game working")
        root.update()


root = Tk()

Label(root, text="your game here")
pause = False

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quit_callback)
root.after(0, game_loop)
root.mainloop()
```